# As basic as possible: jQuery Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, contacts

I'd like to create a very basic contact form. I've got the HTML, Javascript, and PHP written using what little knowledge I know of the language, but it apparently doesn't work. What's missing?

**The HTML:**

```
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input name="name" value="John Doe" size="30" /><br />
            <input name="email" value="john@doe.com" size="40" /><br />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="subject" value="Subject" size="60" /><br />
            <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="100"></textarea><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**The Javascript:**

```
$('form').submit( function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/process.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function() {
            // Update page with success message
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**The PHP:**

```
<?php 

$recipient = "me@email.com"; //recipient 

$Name = ($_POST['name']); //senders name 
$email = ($_POST['email']); //senders e-mail adress 
$mail_body = ($_POST['message']); //mail body 
$subject = ($_POST['subject']); //subject 

$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields 

mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header); //mail command :) 
?>
```

Comment: `.serialize()` is a method, not an attribute.

Comment: So again, Exactly what is it that's NOT working

Comment: Well, as it stands now, when I click the submit button the values of the form appear after a '?' in the address bar and nothing happens. I even tried commenting out the contents of the function to just display an alert but to no avail!

Comment: @BenjiBee - Is your code in a `document.ready` wrapper?

Comment: @Nick - No, no it was not. This is week two of learning Javascript and I have just learned a vert valuable lesson.

The form now works, thank you. How silly.

Any other recommendations for things I may have overlooked or oversimplified, I feel like contact forms are always much more complicated than this for security reasons, etc. is the rest all necessary?

Comment: Nope, they don't need to be complicated really, only as much business logic as you *have* to have, otherwise there's no reason to over-complicate it.

Comment: Well I searched high and low and ended up writing my code the best I could from scratch, so maybe the above code will be helpful to another who needs a very basic contact form! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update for edited question/comments:*
Are you sure your code is running in a `document.ready` handler?, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('form').submit( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/process.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function() {
            // Update page with success message
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

From your comments, it appears your [`.submit()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) isn't rigged up at all, and it's doing the default GET browser behavior.

Comment: Oops, thanks for that. Just a typo in this post, I edited it a bit too heavily when I pasted it here.

Comment: @BenjiBee - Your code looks alright in that case, but if you've greatly simplified it, then you've probably edited out the issue.

Comment: @Zane - Please look before voting, it's obvious from the comments from the OP and Harmen that the question was edited and fixed.